# Can't start ubuntu normally after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

Now I am already in Ubuntu 16.04 but my machine start only with Upstart option in boot menu. If I use normal boot, the screen is blank with this error:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlighe Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
See 'systemctl status systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service' for details
```

Who could help me?